# Get children of page on multi language site Umbraco8

Tags: c#, umbraco8

I have 3 languages on my site, and i am trying to get links for the navigation.

So from my frontpage, i am trying to get the children of that page. But it asks about something called a predicate?

i am using this:

```
children = currentPage.AncestorOrSelf<Frontpage>().Children();
```

how do i use the predicate? I just need the children of the frontpage, so i can build a navigation.

I have tried looking at the documentation, but have been unable to see a solution.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems it takes a lambda expression to sort the data. Or i can just remove() and do .children
Then i just get the children.
Guess thats a change from v7 to v8.